# wordpress malware files inspection

Tags: wordpress, malware

i found few suspicious file (wp-credit.php) in my wordpress site which is not related to wordpress default files , by running it create another file with name ( w-credits.php)
need help in analyzing it because its encrypted

1 ) wp-credit.php  ( http://pastebin.com/zn3Ck0ME  or http://www.pastebin.ca/3031425 )

2 ) wp-credits.php created by wp-credit.php when run it (http://www.pastebin.ca/3031424 )

3 ) wp-searches.php ( http://www.pastebin.ca/3031436 )

Comment: You won't be able to see this resolved into code until you decrypt the code, which could take forever in terms of brute-forcing.  What you could do, however, is make a honeypot.  Replace the scripts with something that logs $_GET and $_POST requests and wait until the keys come through.  For what it's worth, wp-credits.php and wp-searches.php register as common malware (blocked by a firewall in my building.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to "brute force decrypt" any of these files. They're all just slight obfuscations of PHP source code. Web sites like [unphp.net](http://www.unphp.net/) can get you a long way towards readable source code.

- `wp-credit.php` appears to be a backdoor program. It looks through values in the $_COOKIE superglobal for encrypted code, a key and maybe an authorization code. It decrypts the encrypted code and eval's it.
- `wp-credits.php` and `wp-searches.php`, when de-obfuscated, give version 2.5 of "Web Shell by oRb", possibly the most popular of the PHP web shells.

You should (hopefully already have) look through your WordPress installation to see where the `wp-credit.php` file came from. There's unfortunately a myriad of possibilities here, from WordPress bugs, to themes with code injections, to having guessed your WordPress admin login and password.